# Html Div Link covers an entire background row

Tags: html, css, image

I just made a div-link with an image src. Almost everything is ok nevertheless the image-link-div, although its positioned just where i want to it to be, covers (as a link) an entire row from left to right, like it is using an entire line. Any object I put near the code gets placed after (above) or before (bottom) of this invisible link row. Any help ?

**The image its just the Google homepage logo on every navigation: 
white background

properties:

width - 70px
height - 38px (auto stretched on paint, saved as .jpg)

CSS:

```
.box4
{   
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 80%;  
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box4" onclick="location.href='https://www.google.cl'" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="Imagenes/Google.jpg"> </div>
```

Comment: Could you create a JS Fiddle of your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m01tauda/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the problem with your *div-link* :

- `<div>` uses by default `display: block`, you don't need to define it for `div`s
- all of your other "boxes" use `float: left` which reduces width of block to it's minimum if `width` is not specified and removes what you call "invisible link row"
- learn more about `display` and `float` attributes, it's hard to create a layout if you don't know absolute basics of CSS